# Django Rest Framework authentication from a pure JavaScript app

Tags: reactjs, authentication, django-rest-framework, single-page-application

This is heavily discussed across many SO questions, but none I've read address the two specific questions I have.

I'm trying to determine the best authentication model for a DRF private API with a static JavaScript React front end. All traffic via HTTPS.

Given that the URL structure will be:

```
https://app.example.com (front end)
https://app.example.com/api/ (API)
```

My login endpoint is currently setup as per the [DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) for token auth, as regular class-based views.

**1)** Because the front end is pure JavaScript, I don't currently have a way to handle CSRF protection. Does this leave me open to CSRF or CSS attack?

**2)** Is there a way to do session or token auth with a login form created in pure static JavaScript? Or do I always need a server side wrapper for the JavaScript app in order to properly handle CSRF/CSS risk?